# CSS Custom Radiobutton without text

Tags: css, radio-button, less

Im searching the best way to style a custom radio button with pure CSS but without a label or label text.

At the moment I did something like that: (without the different states for checked, disabled etc)

```
input[type=radio] {
 width   : 28px;
 margin  : 0;
 padding : 0;
 opacity : 0;

 & + label {
  background: url("radio_unselected.png") no-repeat 0 2px;
  padding-left : 28px;
  line-height  : 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
```

That works perfectly as long as I got a label for my radios. As soon as I remove the label OR remove the label text, nothing is displayed. What is the best way to achieve my goal. Should I remove the background styles from the & + label and add it as background of the input itself and adjust the position so the radio would overlap the default radio style?

Ty for your help,
Andy

EDIT:

I added at least

```
&:before {
  content:"";
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Now I can actually add a label without text, but still not the perfect solution because a label tag is required.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into the same dilemma. I want to use radio buttons as a pagination control for an image carousel. I came up with this:

```
input[type=radio] {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;

  margin-left: 5px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

input[type=radio]:before {
  content: "";
  visibility: visible;
  position: absolute;

  border: 2px solid #eb6864;
  border-radius: 50%;

  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

input[type=radio]:checked:before {
  background-color: #eb6864;
}
```

This works without any extra markup. Here's the example I'm using for my carousel:

```
<input type='radio' name='test'>
<input type='radio' name='test' checked>
<input type='radio' name='test'>
<input type='radio' name='test'>
<input type='radio' name='test'>
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mEGF7/41/). I've only tested this in a recent build of Chrome; I have no idea how compatible it is.

Comment: hey buddym ty for your help. I will definitely have a look into it and just demarked by own accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<label>
   <input type="radio" value="1">
   <div></div>
</label>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type="radio"] {
   display: none;
}

input[type="radio"] + div {
   height: 20px;
   width: 20px;
   display: inline-block;
   cursor: pointer;
   vertical-align: middle;
   background: #FFF;
   border: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
   border-radius: 100%;
}

input[type="radio"] + div:hover {
    border-color: #c2c2c2;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + div {
    background:gray;
}
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/nuzhysgg/**

Comment: ty for your post, but im searching a solution without another html element. With your code its more or less the same as with a label tag. Instead of the label I just have to add a div after every input :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is no perfect solution. You actually need to have an element like the label or a div/etc tag to change the radio style. One possibility is to build your radios with a label around the input field:

```
<label>
 <input type="radio"....../>
</label>
```

Then you can actually try to add the styling through css. Not the best solution in my opinion, but it makes the styling a lot easier.